# Regex error python

Tags: python, regex

When I use this expression:

```
^(?:[\w]\:|\\)(\\[A-Za-z_\-\s0-9\.]+)+\>$
```

It matches:

```
C:\Users\username>
```

I check it there: http://pythex.org/

It returns me the following error:

```
raise error, v # invalid expression

sre_constants.error: nothing to repeat
```

I read that it can be a bug in Python. But how can I explain it?

Comment: Post more details related to eg.

Comment: You must be using a non-raw string literal. Use [`r'^(?:\w:|\\)(\\[A-Za-z_\s0-9.-]+)+>$'`](https://ideone.com/oA2zED). Although, I tried your regex and it throws an `unbalanced parenthesis` error. Please show your code.

Comment: I think there is a typo somewhere in your code.

Comment: Thanks, it worked for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import re
pattern = r'^(?:\w:|\\)(\\[\w\s_.]+)+>$'
print re.search(pattern, 'C:\Users\username>').group(1)
```

Result:`\username`

Comment: *I read that it can be a bug in Python. But how can I explain it?* - How can you explain it?

Comment: Sorry for my English. :)